# WooCommerce custom loop pagination on front page

Tags: loop, pagination, woocommerce-offtopic

I'm having custom page template that I use as front page of my theme. In that page i have section which lists woocommerce products using custom loop. I want to insert next posts pagination to that section. I'm using next_posts_link() function to generate next page url link. It generates this perfectly, but on my home page page/2 isn't displaying new products but old ones.

Here is my code:

```
    $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;

    $args = array(
       'post_type'      => 'product',
       'posts_per_page' => $top_selling_products_nr,
       'meta_key'       => 'total_sales',
       'paged'          => $paged,
       'orderby'        => 'meta_value_num'
    );

    <?php if ( $woo_home_query->have_posts() ) : ?>

        <div class="products container grid-wrapper clear">

            <div class="row">
            <?php

                while ( $woo_home_query->have_posts() ) : $woo_home_query->the_post();
                    wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
                endwhile;

            ?>
            </div>

            <?php if ( $woo_home_query->max_num_pages > 1 ) : ?>

                <nav class="navigation is posts-navigation" role="navigation">
                    <h2 class="screen-reader-text"><?php esc_html_e( 'Posts navigation', 'goodz' ); ?></h2>
                    <div id="infinite-handle" class="nav-links">
                       <div class="nav-previous"><?php next_posts_link( esc_html__( 'Load More', 'goodz' ), $woo_home_query->max_num_pages ); ?></div>
                    </div> <!-- .nav-links -->
                </nav> <!-- .navigation -->

            <?php endif; ?>

        </div>

    <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score -2):

Can you please try below code?

```
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;

    $woo_home_query = array(
       'post_type'      => 'product',
       'posts_per_page' => $top_selling_products_nr,
       'meta_key'       => 'total_sales',
       'paged'          => $paged,
       'orderby'        => 'meta_value_num'
    );

    <?php if ( $woo_home_query->have_posts() ) : ?>

        <div class="products container grid-wrapper clear">

            <div class="row">
            <?php

                while ( $woo_home_query->have_posts() ) : $woo_home_query->the_post();
                    wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
                endwhile;

            ?>
            </div>

            <?php 
            $total_pages = $woo_home_query->max_num_pages;

            if ($total_pages > 1){

                $current_page = max(1, get_query_var('paged'));

                echo paginate_links(array(
                    'base' => get_pagenum_link(1) . '%_%',
                    'format' => '/page/%#%',
                    'current' => $current_page,
                    'total' => $total_pages,
                    'prev_text'    => __('« prev'),
                    'next_text'    => __('next »'),
                ));
            }
            ?>  

        </div>

    <?php endif; ?>
```